# Can't Open Web forms for marketers Form Designer or Security Manager

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have had WFFM running on a Sitecore instance for a while, but it has recently stopped working. When I go to "Form Designer" on an existing form, I get the standard Sitecore "The requested document was not found" page.

> Requested URL: /applications/modules/web
>
> User Name: sitecore\admin
>
> Site Name: shell
>
> If the page you are trying to display exists, please check that an
>   appropriate prefix has been added to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in
>   the web.config.

Note that the requested URL is stated as `/applications/modules/web` instead of `/applications/modules/web forms for marketers`.

A lot of development has occurred on this site recently, so I'm not sure when exactly this started happening.

Additional: info:

- Folder and file permissions are correct.
- I've tried reinstalling the WFFM package, and made sure that all the files are in place.
- Several processors have been added to the HttpBeginRequest pipeline, but I removed them all to test if they were the cause - they weren't.
- I haven't upgraded Sitecore since WFFM was working and the version is correct.
- No errors are logged

***EDIT***

This also seems to be affecting the Sitecore Security Editor:

> Requested URL: /appl
>
> User Name: sitecore\admin
>
> Site Name: shell
>
> If the page you are trying to display exists, please check that an
>   appropriate prefix has been added to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in
>   the web.config.

***EDIT 2***

Further investigation with this is making me think it is related to the Requested URL. I originally thought the the "Not found" page was displaying the requested url incorrectly. However, if I attempt to goto `mysite.com/sitecore/shell/applications/fake folder with spaces/fake page with spaces` I get this error message:

> Requested URL: /applications/fake folder with spaces/fake page with
>   spaces
>
> User Name: sitecore\admin
>
> Site Name: shell
>
> If the page you are trying to display exists, please check that an
>   appropriate prefix has been added to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in
>   the web.config.

As you can see the Requested Url is correct in the error message. So in relation to my problem, I think maybe Sitecore is requesting the wrong URL in the first place.

Additionally if I go to the go the following url by typing directly into the browser, then the Security Editor opens as expected:
`mysite.com/sitecore/shell/Applications/Security/User-Editor`

Comment: Have you checked folder and file permissions?

Comment: Has anything been added to the HttpRequestPipeline that may be intercepting these requests and sending you to the wrong URL?  Something like a 301 redirect module?

Comment: Was Site core upgraded?  Maybe the DLL's changed.  Maybe you are no longer using the correct version of the WFFM module for your version of Sitecore.

Comment: Have you found anything useful in the Site core logs?

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with Site core support?  I believe the WFFM module is a supported module.

Comment: Gotcha.  To open the ticket you do need access to support.sitecore.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite old now but I thought I'd provide an update for anyone else who encounters the problem.

Unfortunately, Sitecore support weren't able to help beyond pointing out that setting the addAspxExtension attribute to 'true' in the link provider seemed to solve the problem. This may have been acceptable except that extensionless URLs were important to the customer.

In the end I had to amend my link provider so that addAspxExtension is set to 'true' in the web config, and then I set it to false inside the GetItemUrl method for specified sites only.

So now whenever the context site is 'Shell' or 'Admin' etc, the extensions are added by default, but switched off in my main website.

Of course, this is a work around. I still don't know how to actually *fix* the problem

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing that I am going to tell you is that I suspect that there is something wrong with your site declaration for Sitecore Modules. In your web.config, there's a site declaration for "modules_shell" and "modules_website". Those are where the code files that run the modules are usually located... a shell folder to run the parts that run in the Sitecore shell and a web folder to run the part that is accessed by the externally facing site.  Please check your site declarations (and the form.config file) to make sure that you're not in live mode or something like that.   I would definitely say that this is where you should start looking.

The next thing is to say that your comments about Sitecore not serving a url in the /sitecore/shell directory is really not surprising.  Sitecore processes all requests unless you specifically tell it to ignore requests (like setting it in the IgnoreUrlPrefixes in web.config), it's going to try processing it.  Like going to /sitecore/shell/applications gives me a layout error because it doesn't have anything set to handle that request.  Now your error suggests that there is something wrong with Site declarations.. however, even if they were all right, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have checked the "modules_shell" and "modules_website" site declarations and they are identical to a vanilla Sitecore installation (as are the corresponding folder structures). Also, we are not running in Live mode.

Comment: My comments about "/sitecore/shell" were to demonstrate that the URLs reported in the error page are different from the ones Sitecore should be calling internally to open the pages, which seems strange. For example - "Requested URL: /appl"